# Using Zend Json Server, ajax call to list certain information in a css popup

Tags: php, css, json, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I would like to know the best practice to use when listing items from a database in an ajax call with Zend Framework. The end result is to show notes concerning a customer in a css popup when clicking on a link.

I'm currently looking into using Zend_Json_Server, but I can't really see how I could implement it. Is Zend_Json_Server good to use in these cases - and if so, should I use it outside the MVC structure as some suggest?

Most importantly:
Could someone please give me an example of how it could look like?
From Calling the javascript function from the view to listing the items in the CSS div (popup).

This would help immensely and would be really interesting to know about!

KR

Josef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have certainly seen commentary - I think by [MWOP himself](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/227-Exposing-Service-APIs-via-Zend-Framework.html) - that you want API service calls to be fast; if you are only returning JSON, for example, then you don't really need the full MVC. On the other hand, the context-switch action-helper is part of the MVC stack and is often used to handle AJAX calls. I guess idea is that if your AJAX call needs to perform much of the same processing as a standard MVC request, differing only in the return, then it might be DRY-er, albeit slower, to simply use the context-switch. If speed/performance is the issue, then perhaps a separate service might be warranted.

But I confess I have no experience here, so if I am just shooting crap, please feel free to correct me. ;-)

The MWOP link above contains some ideas for how to set up service endpoints.

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much. You pointed me in the right direction. I used ActionContext and it works like a charm with just a few rows of code. After I read your comment I found these: 

http://blog.jtclark.ca/2010/03/zend-framework-and-ajax/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrw8TP62-XU

Which gave a thorughly description of ActionContext. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. Nice link on the context-helper. Thanks for the accept. Cheers!